# how to call dll file without using statment in c#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, call, late-binding

How do I call a DLL written in C#, from my C# main project without using the `using statement`?

As in `CreateObject(servername.typename[,location])` in VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest methods in the .Net framework equivalent to VB6's CreateObject call are the following:

```
object calcInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(calcType);
or    
Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\Test.dll");
```

Code taken from http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/

Answer (score 1):

Keep the same namespace in both the DLL and main project.

Comment: Or write the full namespace of the function you want to call, e.g. `Nike.Shoes.CreateObject()`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your scenario a bit more ? Are you creating some sort of 'plug-in' architecture, where you don't know what plug-ins will be available until runtime ? If so, yes reflection will get you to where you need to go, but there are better ways.